# Database diagram of event_tracker database in MMC

Tags: database, mule

Is there anyway to see the SQL or tables in event_tracker database that Mule Management Console uses to store transaction data?

Answer (score 0):

Database dump for the database, perhaps? mysqldump for v. 3.4.2:

```
CREATE TABLE `EVENTS` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`EXCEPTION_DETAILS` text,
`FLOW_NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`MESSAGE_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`SERVER_ID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`SERVER_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`TRANSACTION_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `E_TRANSACTION_ID` (`TRANSACTION_ID`)
);
CREATE TABLE `EVENT_PROPERTIES` (
`id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`KEY0` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`VALUE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `E_PROPERTIES_KEY` (`KEY0`),
KEY `I_VNT_RTS_ID` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE` (
`ID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`SEQUENCE_VALUE` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
CREATE TABLE `TRANSACTION_SUMMARIES` (
`ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`APPLICATION_NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`CUSTOM_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`PROCESSING_TIME` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`STATUS_LABEL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`STATUS_ORDINAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `T_S_APPLICATION_NAME` (`APPLICATION_NAME`),
KEY `T_S_CUSTOM_ID` (`CUSTOM_ID`),
KEY `T_S_STATUS_LABEL` (`STATUS_LABEL`),
KEY `T_S_TIMESTAMP` (`TIMESTAMP`)
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have the setup ready, wanted to know the table details.